# Property 'item' is 'Read Only'

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am getting the above error when I run my code. I think this is because the DataReader is Read-Only and therefore unable to amend the value. As a new user still getting to grips with vb.Net coming from php/mysql background, can someone show me the correct way to code this please or offer an alternative method.  Many thanks

```
     While dr.Read()
        If dr.HasRows Then

          lvRequests.Items.Add((dr(0)).ToString()).UseItemStyleForSubItems = False
          lvRequests.Items(lvRequests.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(CDate(dr(5)).ToShortDateString())
          lvRequests.Items(lvRequests.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(dr(1).ToString())
          With lvRequests.Items(lvRequests.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(dr(3).ToString())
             If dr(3) Is "D" Then    
                dr(3) = "destroyed"  <--- ERROR

             ElseIf dr(3) Is "O" Then
                dr(3) = "out"        <--- ERROR

             End If

           End With

           lvRequests.Items(lvRequests.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(dr(9).ToString())

           lvcount += 1
         End If

    End While
```

Comment: You cannot change the value of a field in a `DataReader`. Fill a `DataTable` instead which you can modify or -better- change the value already in the SQL.

Comment: Would you have an example please Tim. Thanks

Comment: Difficult without more informations. You haven't provided the schema of your table(s), but you can use `CASE` in sql.

Comment: Can I not create a subitem based on my code? Thanks

Comment: You could create an `object` for each row returned from the reader then modify the properties of the `object`.

Comment: Do you have an example of that Ric. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the value of a datareader. Instead of this

```
      With lvRequests.Items(lvRequests.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(dr(3).ToString())
         If dr(3) Is "D" Then    
            dr(3) = "destroyed"  <--- ERROR

         ElseIf dr(3) Is "O" Then
            dr(3) = "out"        <--- ERROR

         End If

       End With
```

Do something like this

```
         If dr(3).ToString() = "D" Then    
            lvRequests.Items(lvRequests.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add("destroyed")

         ElseIf dr(3).ToString = "O" Then
            lvRequests.Items(lvRequests.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add("out")

         Else

            lvRequests.Items(lvRequests.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(dr(3).ToString())
         End If
```

Comment: lotus, thanks for that. 1 problem however. I need to amend not add. That just adds another column and stops my column 4 from displaying

Comment: lotus. Sorry my bad. Thanks